# maven tomcat7:run configure datasource

Tags: datasource, jndi, maven-tomcat-plugin

I have a multimodule maven project, and I want to use it with **tomcat7 maven plugin** and start it with:

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

But I can't figure out how to configure a jndi datasource.
I've tried to put in my *pom.xml*:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
     <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.0</version>
     <configuration>
          <contextFile>tomcat/context.xml</contextFile>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and in the *context.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/AppealDS" url="jdbc:hsqldb:file:database/appeal"
         driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" username="appeal"
         password="appeal" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         maxActive="3" maxIdle="2" maxWait="10000" />
 </Context>
```

But it doesn't work...How can I register the jndi datasource?

Answer (score 1):

What is the error message?
Use:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
 <configuration>
      <contextFile>tomcat/context.xml</contextFile>
 </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Maybe your jdbc driver is not available in the classpath?

Try adding him in the plugin dependency

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
 <configuration>
      <contextFile>tomcat/context.xml</contextFile>
 </configuration>
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
   here your hsql version
   </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I have a problem when the application try to get it...it throws an exception saying taht the *jdbc/* can't be found...

Comment: You could try the contextFile param like this: '${basedir}/tomcat/context.xml'